# How to use existing virtual enviroment without running pipenv install

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-3.7, pipenv

I have a project that has a python3.7 virtual environment created by pipenv. I would like to run the project without running `pipenv install` since I don't have python3.7 interpreter and can not install it.

Could I use run the project without creating new virtual env from the existing one?

I have tried to activate the existing virtual env by running

```sh
source path_to_.venv/bin/activate
```

then I set PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH to path_to_.venv/lib/python3.7 
then I executed :

```sh
path_to_.venv/bin/python main.py
```

I got the following output :

`Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: Unable to get the locale encoding`
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'`

Comment: When you run `source path_to_.venv/bin/activate`, the command prompt for your shell change?

Comment: Why are you setting PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH? `activate` takes care of everything, setting those variables can only lead to issues.

Comment: If you already have the venv, why not just use it directly? Why do you modify ``PYTHONHOME`` and ``PYTHONPATH`` instead of trusting the ``bin/activate``  to do its job?

Comment: Yes, my shell command prompt change but when I open python command line it gives me python2.7

Comment: I changed PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH because when I run **python main.py** It gives me library dependencies issue and my shell suggest that I change those variables.